# How to fix? Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "x" violates foreign key constraint "y_fkey"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

This error is showing when I attempt to `POST` / create a new contact in the database. This is the error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "contacts" violates foreign key constraint "org_name_fkey"`. Below are the models, does anyone know how to fix this? All of the other fields `POST` fine, it is only when attempted to add `org_name`. If I don't include `org_name` in the `POST` everything stores in the postgres database.

**Contact Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Contacts = sequelize.define('contact', {
      contact_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'contact_id',
        primaryKey: 'true'
      },
      first_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
      },
      last_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
      },
      contact_type_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        references: {
          model: 'contact_type',
          key: 'contact_type_id'
        }
      },
      org_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        references: {
          model: 'org',
          key: 'org_name'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'contacts',
    }
  );

  Contacts.associate = (models) => {
    Contacts.belongsTo(models.contact_type, {foreignKey: 'contact_type_id'});
    Contacts.belongsTo(models.org, {foreignKey: 'org_name'});
  };

  return Contacts;
};
```

**Contact Type Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ContactType = sequelize.define('contact_type', {
      // attributes
      contact_type_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'contact_type_id'
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'updated_at'        
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'created_at'
      }
    },
  );

  ContactType.associate = (models) => {
    ContactType.hasOne(models.contact, {foreignKey: 'contact_id'});
  };

  return ContactType;
};
```

**Org Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Org = sequelize.define('org', {
      org_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'org_name',
        primaryKey: 'true'
      },
      org_type_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'org_type_id'
      },
      website: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'website'
      }
    },
  );

  Org.associate = (models) => {
    Org.hasMany(models.contact, {foreignKey: 'contact_id'});
  };

  return Org;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that error tells you is that whatever `org_name` you are passing into your POST request does not have a corresponding `Org` record in the database. i.e. You are creating a person who works at ABC Corp, but you haven't added ABC Corp to your Orgs. You would have to fix this by creating the Org first, then the Contact.

You do not give the exact request that causes the error. This would be helpful in tracking down your issue. Also, you should query your database to find the state of the Org table before the POST. Perhaps you forgot to call `save` on the Org instance.

Comment: aw yes this makes sense, let me try this then will verify this is the correct answer, thanks